# May the query optimizer change the order of joins if left join is followed by inner join

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a belief that the order of `joins` if `outer and inner joins` are involved may lead to different results if join order changed.

> Does the `optimizer` still have autonomy to change `join order` in this regard?

Comment: A query planner cannot cause the result set to be semantically different - or else it would be broken. But it can do anything it darn well pleases if it ensures the result set is semantically identical to the 'unaltered' query. Thus a better question may be: "Can the order of LEFT and INNER joins affect the result?" (Although the type of joins is confused/differing throughout the question title and body as it is currently written.)

Comment: Depends on the dbms product used. Different products optimize in different ways. Which dbms are you asking about?

Comment: I was refereing to SQL Server, however the answer above satisfies me. Thanks a lot.